# Standard matrix for an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Someone please help me to with this:

> Suppose $P$ is the standard matrix for an orthogonal projection of $\Bbb R^n$ onto a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Prove that $I − P$ is the standard matrix for an orthogonal projection of $\Bbb R^n$ onto some subspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fact: $P$ is a projection matrix iff $P^2 = P$.

So, we need to show that $P^2 = P \implies (I-P)^2 = I-P$.

Do you see how to do this?

EDIT: As mentioned by  Vedran Šego in the comments below, the above only shows that $P$ is a projection matrix, not necessarily an orthogonal projection matrix. To show that $P$ is an orthogonal projection matrix, we also need to show that $P$ is symmetric $\implies$ $I-P$ is symmetric.

Comment: yes (I-P)^2=I^2+P^2-2IP=I-P

Comment: so just like this i think this prove I-P is idempotent

Comment: Yes, that is also what you need to do to prove something is an idempotent.

Comment: One still needs to show that $I - P$ is symmetric (which is obvious, but still needs to be mentioned). Without the symmetricity, the projection is not orthogonal.

Comment: is what i do symmetric (I-P)^T=I^T-p^T=I-(M (M^TM)^-1 M^T)^T=I-M (M^TM)^-1 M^T=I-P

Comment: @user146264 Notice that $P$ is also an orthogonal projection matrix, hence symmetric. So, $P^T = P$. There is no need for $M$ and $T$.

Comment: so how i can prove it without M&T ,i have to prove  (I-P)^T=(I-P)?

Comment: @user146264 You got $(I-P)^T = I^T - P^T = I - P^T$ and you know that $P^T = P$. So...?

Comment: thank for your helping and what about if i have to prove P^k is idempotent:(P^k)^2=P^k and symmetric (P^k)^T=P^k is that correct?

Comment: You can show by induction that $P^n = P$ for all integers $n \ge 1$. Then, $(P^k)^2 = P^{2k} = P = P^k$.

Comment: can u please explain more for last thing? i mean this part nduction that P^n=P

Comment: can i say p^k=p^k-2 .P^2=p^k-2 then p^k-2 =p^k-4 p^2=P^k-4 then do that many times we have p?

Comment: If $P^n = P$, then $P^{n+1} = P^2P^{n-1} = PP^{n-1} = P^n = P$.

Comment: thank u so much and  to prove the symmetric just say as we done for  idempotent:  (P^k)^T=p^k