# Project orthonormal vectors onto subspace while preserving orthonormality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthonormal, projection

Suppose I have $m$ orthonormal vectors $u_1, ..., u_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $m < n$. I would like to project each vector onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ using some linear transformation $W: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $Wu_1, ..., Wu_m \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are orthonormal vectors.

How would I go about finding such a matrix $W$?

Comment: You could just define $W$ to send $u_i$ to $e_i$ where $e_i\in\mathbb R^m$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector. To make this a map on all of $\mathbb R^n$, just extend the $u_i$'s to a basis and send the other stuff to zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard matrix for an orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848917/standard-matrix-for-an-orthogonal-projection)

Comment: @Croissant It's unclear (to me at least) how the question you have linked is connected to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to take $W$ to be the matrix whose rows are $u_1,\dots,u_m$.